GUI Designer form file is not rendered
We have a lot of IntelliJ IDEA GUI forms in our project. A few of them are broken (for years). I decided to fix it. I know it is discouraged to manually edit those XML files, but here we are. I don't see any way around it (other than recreating those forms from scratch which is a risky and time-consuming strategy)
In case you're wondering what I mean by “broken”, it's the IDE's failure to render the form file. No exceptions or error messages. It looks like this

After investigation, I found out that BookingPane is actually fine, the problem is with its nested form, GraphPane. I commented in and out parts of the GraphPane form, and here's what I discovered. When you comment out the last declared component, it's rendered fine in the IDE. The snippet below is the file in full
BookingHeader used to contain some paintComponent() code, but now I removed all of it, and the problem still persists

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns="http://www.intellij.com/uidesigner/form/" version="1" bind-to-class="graph.GraphPane">
 <grid id="27dc6" binding="mainPanel" layout-manager="GridBagLayout">
   <constraints>
     <xy x="20" y="20" width="704" height="400"/>
   </constraints>
   <properties/>
   <border type="none"/>
   <children>
     <scrollpane id="3b41b" binding="bookingScrollPane">
       <constraints>
         <grid row="1" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="7" hsize-policy="7" anchor="0" fill="3" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false">
           <minimum-size width="700" height="-1"/>
           <preferred-size width="700" height="-1"/>
         </grid>
         <gridbag weightx="1.0" weighty="1.0"/>
       </constraints>
       <properties>
         <minimumSize width="700" height="-1"/>
         <verticalScrollBarPolicy value="22"/>
       </properties>
       <border type="none"/>
       <children>
         <component id="accb1" class="booking.BookingPanel" binding="bookingPanel">
           <constraints/>
           <properties>
             <background color="-1"/>
           </properties>
         </component>
       </children>
     </scrollpane>
     <grid id="25314" layout-manager="BorderLayout" hgap="0" vgap="0">
       <constraints>
         <grid row="0" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="3" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="3" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
         <gridbag weightx="0.0" weighty="0.0"/>
       </constraints>
       <properties/>
       <border type="none"/>
       <children> <!--
         <component id="e6331" class="booking.BookingHeader" binding="bookingHeader">
           <constraints border-constraint="Center"/>
           <properties>
             <background color="-1"/>
             <focusable value="true"/>
             <minimumSize width="10" height="17"/>
             <opaque value="true"/>
             <preferredSize width="10" height="17"/>
           </properties>
         </component> -->
         <grid id="b94e8" layout-manager="GridLayoutManager" row-count="1" column-count="1" same-size-horizontally="false" same-size-vertically="false" hgap="-1" vgap="-1">
           <margin top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0"/>
           <constraints border-constraint="East"/>
           <properties>
             <maximumSize width="17" height="15"/>
             <minimumSize width="17" height="15"/>
             <preferredSize width="17" height="15"/>
           </properties>
           <border type="none"/>
           <children/>
         </grid>
       </children>
     </grid>
   </children>
 </grid>
</form>



package booking;

import javax.swing.*;
 

// removed all the code
public class BookingHeader extends JPanel {}



If I reintroduce the last component (with the id e6331), I get a similar “broken” effect

What's wrong with the form file?
IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-241.14494.240, built on March 28, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+8-b1207.12 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 4
Registry:
 ide.experimental.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
 Lombook Plugin (241.14494.240)
 AntSupport (241.14494.158)
Kotlin: 241.14494.240-IJ


It turned out BookingHeader's paintComponent() threw during rendering. If you encounter a similar problem, check the IDE's logs (Help -> Show Log in Explorer)
// BookingHeader

    private Date dateBgn; // not initialized

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // ...
        calendar.setTime(dateBgn);

// java.util.Calendar#setTime

    public final void setTime(Date date) {
        setTimeInMillis(date.getTime()); // NPE is date is null
    }

Commenting out BookingHeader's code didn't help because it was cached by IntelliJ. Apparently, in some special type of cache that is not invalidated by Invalidate caches. The only sure way to invalidate it is to execute Reload Custom Components (I had to search for it via Ctrl+N: it's not clear where it's located in the menu bar)
